# Optimize trivial summation in calculation of geometric distribution

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, distribution

```
def geo_dist_names(p, k):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(1, 4):
        sum += p**i   
    return (p**(1+k))/sum
```

*p* is a float between 0 and 1 and *k* is an int between 0 and 3.
The function basically just find the value in a geometric distribution associated with the given *p* and *k* and then normalizes this by dividing with the sum of the 4 potential values for *k*.

It works, but I am calling this function many times so I wondered if there were a more optimized way of performing this operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vectorial version of your code would be:

```
import numpy as np

def geo_dist_names(p, k):
    return (p**(1+k))/(p**np.arange(1,4)).sum()
```

Yet, I'm not sure that it will be faster than pure python as the range is quite small here, so the overhead of numpy is probably not negligible.

**Edit.** Indeed, assuming:

```
def geo_dist_names_python(p, k, N=4):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(1, N):
        sum += p**i   
    return (p**(1+k))/sum

def geo_dist_names_numpy(p, k, N=4):
    return (p**(1+k))/(p**np.arange(1,N)).sum()
```

numpy is better only when the range increases:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if it's more optimized. But as a one-liner you can wright it like this:

```
def geo_dist_names(p, k):
    return (p**(1+k))/(p+p**2+p**3)
```

Comment: @KasperDahlAndersen range(1,4) will return [1,2,3]. Range do not include the stop value.